# Merge multiple date range columns into one date range

Tags: pyspark

I've got a dataframe that looks like this:

| id | value 1 | value 2 | 1_valid_from | 1_valid_to | 2_valid_from | 2_valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 7 | date 1 | date 3 | date 2 | date 4 |
| a | 2 | 8 | date 3 | date 5 | date 4 | date 6 |
| b | 3 | 9 | date 1 | date 6 | date 1 | date 6 |

Basically, per id I have multiple rows, and each row has two date ranges.
These date ranges can overlap, but have no holes in them. For example, for a certain id
the date ranges may look like:

--------- ------ -------------- ---- ----

---- --------- - ---- --- ---------- ----

date ->

Where the holes indicate that the value changed at a certain date, for one of the date ranges, respectively.

I want to merge these date ranges, to create one row per 'merged' date range, so the rows have to be exploded somehow.
In the line visualization, that should look like:

---- ---- ---- - ---- --- ----- ---- ----

As a wanted dataframe, the wanted output is:

| id | value 1 | value 2 | valid_from | valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | null | date 1 | date 2 |
| a | 1 | 7 | date 2 | date 3 |
| a | 2 | 7 | date 3 | date 4 |
| a | 2 | 8 | date 4 | date 5 |
| a | null | 8 | date 5 | date 6 |
| b | 3 | 9 | date 1 | date 6 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you missed adding the example at `or a certain id the date ranges may look like:`. One more question is which fields you need group by? the id only? as the final df you added there are rows with the same id